# having trouble using scipy.optimize.leastsq

Tags: python, eclipse-plugin, scipy, pydev

everything else works fine but when I use the leasesq function the pydev editor have an error that says Undefined variable from import: leastsq what is going on here?

the code is the MIT's python cost model timing.py at the url: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/readings/python-cost-model/timing.py
and the leastsq part is in the function:

```
def fit2(A,b):
""" Relative error minimizer """
def f(x):
    assert len(x) == len(A[0])
    resids = []
    for i in range(len(A)):
        sum = 0.0
        for j in range(len(A[0])):
            sum += A[i][j]*x[j]
        relative_error = (sum-b[i])/b[i]
        resids.append(relative_error)
    return resids
ans = scipy.optimize.leastsq(f,[0.0]*len(A[0]))
# print "ans:",ans
if len(A[0])==1:
    x = [ans[0]]
else:
    x = ans[0]
resids = sum([r*r for r in f(x)])
return (x,resids,0,0)
```

Comment: Do you have trouble when you run your code?

Comment: I cannot run my code due to this error

Comment: how are you importing scipy? show me the money...

Comment: Can you run it outside of PyDev/Eclipse?

Comment: No, I tried but it says unable to find leastsq...

Comment: Do you have an `import scipy.optimize` at the top of your script?

Comment: yes, I have, right before this function

Comment: Is your scipy installation complete?  scipy is a big package and its sometimes possible to pick and choose what is included.

Comment: yes, I can import other packages but leastsq. I tried to install scipy again, but still got this problem

Comment: Paste the complete error message including the traceback.

Comment: After I uninstall all the python develop environment and install it all over again, it's working now, thx guys!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're giving the LSQ-function two keyword arguments, while it requires three. You're supplying it with the function, the initial values, but not with the actual values over which the LSQ is to be made?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard-coding the calculation of the residuals try just wrapping the residuals as a function which is the difference between the data values and the function to minimize:

for example, just fitting a gaussian function to some data set:

```
M = np.array(data) # your data as a Nx2 Matrix of (x, y) data points

initials = [3,2,1] # just some initial guess values

def gaussian(x, p):
    return p[0]*np.exp((-(x-p[1])**2.0)/p[2]**2.0) # definition of the function

def residuals(p, y, x):
    return y - gaussian(x, p) # definition of the residual

cnsts = leastsq(residuals, initials, args=(M[:,1], M[:,0]))[0] # outputs optimized initials
```